# Disable Wifi on Connection to Ethernet with NetworkManager

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, ethernet

How can I disable my Wifi radio when I've connected to a network via Ethernet (wired), but enable the Wifi connection if I don't have a wired connection? Essentially, I want XOR switch for my wired/wireless connection states.

Comment: Here is my alternative and slightly more efficient solution: https://gist.github.com/bulletmark/8e051a0a9ffdce689d86988c528e7764

Comment: Related to https://superuser.com/questions/233448/disable-wlan-if-wired-cable-network-is-available and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271491/disable-wifi-if-lan-is-connected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [a script by Ilija Matoski](https://matoski.com/article/wifi-ethernet-autoswitch/) to accomplish exactly this, which would belong in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/70-wifi-wired-exclusive.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh

name_tag="wifi-wired-exclusive"
syslog_tag="$name_tag"
skip_filename="/etc/NetworkManager/.$name_tag"

if [ -f "$skip_filename" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

interface="$1"
iface_mode="$2"
iface_type=$(nmcli dev | grep "$interface" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
iface_state=$(nmcli dev | grep "$interface" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3)

logger -i -t "$syslog_tag" "Interface: $interface = $iface_state ($iface_type) is $iface_mode"

enable_wifi() {
    logger -i -t "$syslog_tag" "Interface $interface ($iface_type) is down, enabling wifi ..."
    nmcli radio wifi on
}

disable_wifi() {
    logger -i -t "$syslog_tag" "Disabling wifi, ethernet connection detected."
    nmcli radio wifi off
}

if [ "$iface_type" = "ethernet" ] && [ "$iface_mode" = "down" ]; then
    enable_wifi
elif [ "$iface_type" = "ethernet" ] && [ "$iface_mode" = "up"  ] && [ "$iface_state" = "connected" ]; then
    disable_wifi
fi
```

Additionally, to disable this switching operation, you can create the file `/etc/NetworkManager/.wifi-wired-exclusive` (e.g. via `touch`).

Comment: Since this is a recent answer, is there a systemd solution to the same question?

Comment: @Xofo The question specifies NetworkManager, so the systemd solution would be the same. If you mean `systemd-networkd`, that would be a different question.